# Reading an array from XML into a bean using Apache Commons Configuration and BeanUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils, apache-commons-config

In a configuration file I have multiple array values, for example names for a phonebook.

```
<configuration>
    <phonebook>
        <name>John</name>
        <name>Mary</name>
    </phonebook>
</configuration>
```

I want to read these into this bean via BeanHelper (or another way):

```
public interface Phonebook {
    public void setName(String[] names);

    public String[] getName();
}
```

Or ideally with lists `java.util.List<String>` instead of arrays `String[]`.
The implementation of the interface is simple:

```
public class MyPhonebook implements Phonebook {
    private String[] names;
    
    @Override
    public void setName(String[] names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getName() {
        return names;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join("; ", names);
    }
}
```

The main looks like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.XMLBeanDeclaration;

public class Main {

    private static Phonebook myPhonebook;
    private static XMLConfiguration config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // read the configuration
        String configFile = "config.xml";
        try {
            config = new XMLConfiguration();
//            config.setAttributeSplittingDisabled(true);
            config.setFileName(configFile);
            config.load();
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // this is to see which keys and values are inside the configuration
        config.getKeys().forEachRemaining(
                s -> System.out.println(s + " : " + config.getProperty(s)));

        // try to create the bean
        try {
            XMLBeanDeclaration declaration = new XMLBeanDeclaration(config,
                    "phonebook");

            declaration.getBeanProperties().forEach(
                    (k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " : " + v));

            myPhonebook = (Phonebook) BeanHelper.createBean(declaration,
                    MyPhonebook.class);
        } catch (ConfigurationRuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // print out the bean
        System.out.println(myPhonebook);
    }
}
```

This does not work when trying to create the bean, I get a `ConfigurationRuntimeException` caused by this `UnsupportedOperationException`:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to handle collection of type : [Ljava.lang.String; for property name
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createPropertyCollection(BeanHelper.java:335)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBean(BeanHelper.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.DefaultBeanFactory.initBeanInstance(DefaultBeanFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.DefaultBeanFactory.createBean(DefaultBeanFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:390)
    ... 2 more
```

The first thing I had to change was the layout of the XML file to match the documentations of the [XMLBeanDeclaration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/beanutils/XMLBeanDeclaration.html) and the [XMLConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html):

```
<configuration>
    <phonebook name="John,Mary" />
</configuration>
```

If I run the program then, it terminates normally and my output is:

```
phonebook[@name] : [John, Mary]
name : Mary
Mary
```

That means that the `XMLConfiguration` correctly identifies the configuration file having an array in the attribute name, but somehow the XMLBeanDeclaration does not. It always just takes the last value.

I came up with a solution which works, more or less, by abusing the fact that it is possible to read in arrays as single `String`s. I added the line `config.setAttributeSplittingDisabled(true);`. The result is the following:

```
phonebook[@name] : John,Mary
name : John,Mary
John; Mary
```

In this case it seems that on creation of the bean the `BeanHelper` realizes the array and is able to choose the correct method.

Since this makes my configuration a little bit unflexible, I wonder if it is possible to get the `XMLBeanDeclaration` to handle arrays at an earlier stage to avoid the call to `config.setAttributeSplittingDisabled(true);`?

I am using Java 8, Configuration 1.10 and BeanUtils 1.9.2.